# 21.04 Lost GUI for wifi and bluetooth

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I have freshly installed Ubuntu few weeks ago and was using wifi and bluetooth without problems. Today I started the system and I do not see gui for wifi networks and possibility to switch on bluetooth. When I try to restart network manager through `sudo service network-manager restart`I get this error: `Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.`

As I have not changed anything during the weekend I suspect that the culprit could be a failed / corrupted actualization - is that possible? How should I proceed?

EDIT: lspci -v gives following output for the wifi:

```
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595
    Physical Slot: 0
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 12
    I/O ports at 2000 [disabled] [size=256]
    Memory at d0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822be
```

sudo rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT2: rolling back from 5.11.0.31 to 5.11.0.25 restored the wifi

Comment: Please try: `sudo service NetworkManager restart` and tell us if there is an error. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks for the welcome! No error there.